# Can't compare Lines of a file in C

Tags: c, string, window, strstr, strncpy

I got this piece of code:

```
void scanLinesforArray(FILE* file, char search[], int* lineNr){
    char line[1024];
    int line_count = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),file) !=NULL){
        ++line_count;
        printf("%d",line_count);
        printf(line);
        char *temp = malloc(strlen(line));
//      strncpy(temp,line,sizeof(line));
//      printf("%s\n",temp);
        free(temp);
        continue;
    }
}
```

This will print all lines of the file, but as soon as I uncomment the strncpy(), the program just stops without error.

Same happens as soon as I use strstr() to compare the line to my search variable.

I tried the continue statement and other redundant things, but nothing helps.

Comment: Also note that there are cases where [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) will *not* add the string null-terminator. Which means you can't use `temp` as a null-terminated string (which the `%s` format expects). Also remember that `strlen` doesn't include the null-terminator in the length it returns, so you need to allocate one more byte to fit it.

Comment: That seems to be an off-by-one error. NB that ```strlen``` doesn't count the ```'\0'``` byte. You also do not check the return value of ```malloc``` to see if it succeeded.

Comment: You may print both the results out to see the difference between ```sizeof(line)``` and ```strlen(line)```.

Comment: @KingSeyfo "as soon as I use strstr() to compare the line to my search variable." --> post the code that used that.

Answer (score 4):

Many problems:

**Do not print a general string as a format**

Code risks undefined behavior should the string contain a `%`.

```
// printf(line);  // BAD

printf("%s", line);
// or 
fputs(line, stdout);
```

**Bad size**

`strncpy(temp,line,sizeof(line));` is like `strncpy(temp,line, 1024);`, yet `temp` points to less than 1024 allocated bytes.  Code attempts to write outside allocated memory.  Undefined behavior (UB).

Rarely should code use `strncpy()`.

**Bad specifier**

`%s` expects a match *string*.  `temp` does not point to a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.  Instead allocated for the `'\0'`.

```
// printf("%s\n", temp);`.  

char *temp = malloc(strlen(line) + 1); // + 1
strcpy(temp,line);
printf("<%s>", temp);
free(temp);
```

**No compare**

"Can't compare Lines of a file in C" is curious as there is no compare code.

Recall `fgets()` typically retains a `'\n'` in `line[]`.

---

Perhaps

```
long scanLinesforArray(FILE* file, const char search[]){
  char line[1024*4];    // Suggest wider buffer - should be at least as wide as the search string.
  long line_count = 0;  // Suggest wider type
  while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)) {
    line_count++;
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // Lop off potential \n
    if (strcmp(line, search) == 0) {
      return line_count;
    }
  }
  return 0; // No match
}
```

---

Advanced: Sample better performance code.

```
long scanLinesforArray(FILE *file, const char search[]) {
  size_t len = strlen(search);
  size_t sz = len + 1;
  if (sz < BUFSIZ) sz = BUFSIZ;
  if (sz > INT_MAX) {
    return -2; // Too big for fgets()
  }
  char *line = malloc(sz);
  if (line == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }

  long line_count = 0;
  while (fgets(line, (int) sz, file)) {
    line_count++;
    if (memcmp(line, search, len) == 0) {
      if (line[len] == '\n' || line[len] == 0) {
        free(line);
        return line_count;
      }
    }
  }

  free(line);
  return 0; // No match
}
```